# functioning of groupby() method

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

I want to know why are we storing `nyc.groupby('Complaint Type')` in the "groupedby_complaint" variable. What does it return?

```
groupedby_complainttype = nyc.groupby('Complaint Type')
grp_data = groupedby_complainttype.get_group('Illegal Parking')
```

I have already searched it on the google but i cant find satisfactory answers. ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/pablomonleon/311-service-requests-nyc

Comment: Provided above is the link to the dataset i have been analyzing

Comment: It returns... The dataset grouped by your variable.. You can then sum count or perform different aggregation functions